# apt doesn't not install maintainer configuration files during upgrade

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, dpkg

I've setup an unattended upgrade of ubuntu servers 12.04 to 14.04 using `do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive`. To be sure the servers will have the most up-to-date maintainer configuration, I've created a configuration file for APT `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` which contains `'Dpkg::Options { "--force-confdef"; "--force-confnew"; }` which means from what I read in the man page "install the default configuration, replace modified configuration with new configuration".

However upon the upgrade process, I still find files named `*.dpkg-dist` which implies the configuration of the package was not upgraded to the maintainer version. Did I forgot something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify the `force-confdef` because it uses default option provided by package maintainer (whether to use new or old file). If no default option is available then only after that it falls back to the `force-confnew` setting.

What you want is to leave only  `force-confnew` setting.